Passagem do modelo entidade relacionamento(notação (min, max)) para o modelo relacional

Estou com dificuldade para passar essa notação para o modelo relacional, parece que ela difere um pouco das mais comuns, alguém que já trabalhou ou já viu algo parecido poderia explicar como funciona essa tradução do Mer para o modelo relacional?

Segue a imagem

Quem chegou até aqui, e ficou curioso. Pelo que pesquisei se transformaria assim para o modelo relacional.
A(a1, a2, a3, primary key(a1,a2)) //
B(b1, b2, b3, primary key(b1)) //
R(a1(ffk references A),a2(fk references A), b1(fk references B), primary key(a1,a2)) //
